# Can't setup static IP using network/interfaces

Tags: debian, networking

I'm working on BeagleBone Green and have the latest Linux image on my BBG. For networking part, it worked fine until I tried to setup a static IP on `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Here is what I have in my interfaces file.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.51
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

My question is: I'm still able to connect to the network as my BBG got IP address from DHCP regardless of the settings on interfaces file. When I tried to restart networking service, here is what I got.

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The following is the message from `systemctl status networking.service`.

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-17 18:51:28 CST; 1min 1s ago
 Docs: man:interfaces(5)
Process: 2836 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 2831 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && ud
 Main PID: 2836 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG ifup[2836]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG ifup[2836]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 17 18:51:28 BBG systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If I manually brought down eth0 by `sudo ifdown eth0`, here is what I got.

```
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
```

A reboot doesn't help. It still gets IP from DHCP. Any idea what's going on here? Thanks for your time.

In response to Panki's comment, here is the result of `ip a`. In item 4, `192.160.1.106` is the IP address from DHCP, and `192.168.1.51` is the static IP I put in the interfaces file.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
link/can
3: can1: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
link/can
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:5d:ad:37:8e:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.106/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.1.51/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::9a5d:adff:fe37:8eaa/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:5d:ad:37:8e:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: usb1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:5d:ad:37:8e:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.6.2/30 brd 192.168.6.3 scope global usb1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `ip a` in your question?

Comment: The Debian Wiki (https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) states: 
`Make sure to disable all DHCP services, e.g. dhcpcd.`. Did you do that?

Comment: @Panki I have included the result of `ip a` to the original message. @mnille there is no `dhcpcd.service` in my system.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but can you just define the static IP using the router? (That's what I do with my RPi servers.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I somehow fixed the issue, but I don't think I "solved" the problem as I didn't change anything on my BBG. We encountered some issues with our old router (WHR-1166D) and got a replacement (DIR-612). At the beginning, the connection was unstable (from users point of view) because we're able to visit some websites but not the others. It took us a while to figured that the DIR-612 only issued IPv6 IPs to devices that accept IPv6 (pretty much all devices nowadays). After updating the firmware, the IPv6 feature was removed from the DIR-612 and all devices get IPv4 IPs from this router. My BeagleBone then got the IP I assigned in the interfaces file.

I really have no idea why the unstable router (WHR-1166D) and the router that issues IPv6 IPs caused the problem I asked here.